# Returning by reference in C++

Tags: c++, syntax, return-by-reference

I know that it's alright to return by reference if the referenced variable was also passed into the function by reference. For example:

```
int& foo(int& bar)
{
    bar++;
    return bar;
}
```

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to also return by reference if you're returning an object that was created *in* the function via the `new` keyword. I tried something like the following, but got a compiler error:

```
vector<int>& baz()
{
    return new vector<int>();
}
```

Is there a way to return the new vector by reference that makes sense, or is it better to just return a pointer?

Comment: There is no way that would make sense. It would actually make more sense to return the vector by value, then the caller doesn't have to read the docs to figure out it they need to delete the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, you can of course return a dynamically allocated object by reference:

```
vector<int>& baz()
{
    return *new vector<int>();
}
```

Note the `*` used to dereference the pointer returned by `new`.

Whether it's wise to do that is an entirely different kettle of fish. It's a prime candidate for a memory leak. If you do it, the caller is responsible for calling `delete` on the returned object, otherwise it's leaked. Note that this could happen *very easily* with either of these scenarios:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = baz(); // leak!
auto v2 = baz(); // leak!, auto doesn't deduce references
```

In modern C++, you should simply return the vector by value and let move semantics and/or [(Named) Return Value Optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) do its job:

```
std::vector<int> baz()
{
  return std::vector<int>();
}
```

If you *need* dynamic allocation for some reason, you should at least return a suitable smart pointer to ensure no memory leaks can happen:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> baz()
{
  return std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>(new std::vector<int>());
}
```

Comment: +1 for "if you need dynamic allocation." The other answers assumed I didn't.

Comment: @JustinLardinois my answer did assume it! Anyway Angew's one is ways better.

Comment: @Angew you could mention that "std::vector<int> vec_of_int = baz();" is pure evil. Then your answer would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding: `Is there a way to return the new vector by reference that makes sense, or is it better to just return a pointer?`

**A double no no.**

Just return by value and take advantage of copy-elision (See: [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)) and move-semantics (See: [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics))

Answer (score 1):

```
new vector<int>();
```

actually returns a pointer.

If you really like to memory leak, write this:

```
return *(new std::vector<int>());
```

Comment: A nice cynical answer!